# Unwrap UIWindow twice from AppDelegate in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, appdelegate, uiwindow

To Get the rootViewController in Objective-c you can use the below line of code

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController
```

I tried to do the same in swift

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window?.rootViewController
```

But I got this error

> 'UIWindow?' does not have a member named 'rootViewController'

And the suggestion says that you have to unwrap UIWindow twice `UIWindow??` to be

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.rootViewController
```

My Question is: **Why do I need to unwrap the window twice ?**

.

.

---

I have looked in the API and found that

```
protocol UIApplicationDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    optional var window: UIWindow? { get set }
}
```

The window has one optional

```
class UIWindow : UIView {
    var rootViewController: UIViewController?
}
```

Also the rootViewController has one optional

.

.

---

I thought may be because UIWindow in UIApplicationDelegate protocol has `optional` and `UIWindow?` so I tried the below in Playground

```
@objc protocol MyApplicationDelegate {
    optional var myWindow: MyWindow? { get set }
}

class MyWindow : NSObject {
    var rootViewController: Int?
    init(number: Int) {
        rootViewController = number
    }
}

class MyAppDelegate: MyApplicationDelegate {
    var myWindow: MyWindow?
    init() {
        myWindow = MyWindow(number: 5)
    }
}

let myDelegate = MyAppDelegate()
println(myDelegate.myWindow?.rootViewController)
```

However I can get `myWindow` with one optional and can successfully log '5'

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well; I found the problem with my example

In my example I'm creating object from `MyAppDelegate` directly which will sure have `myWindow` property as I'm defining it

Changing the example to be the following

```
@objc protocol MyApplicationDelegate {
    optional var myWindow: MyWindow? { get set }
}

class MyWindow : NSObject {
    var rootViewController: Int?
    init(number: Int) {
        rootViewController = number
    }
}

class MyAppDelegate: MyApplicationDelegate {
    var myWindow: MyWindow?
    init() {
        myWindow = MyWindow(number: 5)
    }
}

class MyApplication: NSObject {
    var myDelegate: MyApplicationDelegate
    override init() {
        myDelegate = MyAppDelegate()
    }
}

let myApplication = MyApplication()
println(myApplication.myDelegate.myWindow??.rootViewController)
```

I needed to add another class `MyApplication` that has a property conform to`MyApplicationDelegate`

So I was able to use **myWindow??** first unwrapping for the `optional` part in the protocol and second one is for the optional declaration in the variable `UIWindow?`